# ORA-28000: the account is locked

Tags: database, oracle

I found this Error When i try to implement label Security

`SQL> conn lbacsys@pdbaait;
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-28000: the account is locked`

Comment: The message is pretty explicit, what is not clear about it?

Comment: How could i connect successfully?

Comment: You, or your dba, need to unlock the account before you can connect to it

Comment: How could i do that please?

Comment: It Worked!! Thank you ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To unlock an account, you have to use the [ALTER USER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4003.htm) command:

`ALTER USER lbacsys IDENTIFIED BY password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;`

Comment: Where should this be entered? I cannot open a connection to directly edit it there.

Comment: As user with the 'ALTER USER' privilege needs to connect to allow the execution of this code